# Custom Role in Azure DevOps to allow Add Users

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, user-permissions, usergroups, project-settings

Is it possible to provide a reduced set of permissions to allow a user permission to add other users to a project without being a full blown administrator?  Adding a user as a Project Admin provides to more access which is a huge security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could add user as contributor or Project Valid Users with limited access. Please see [Project-level groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups)

**Contributors**: Has permissions to contribute fully to the project code base and work item tracking. The main permissions they don't have are those that manage or administer resources.

**Project Valid Users**: Has permissions to access and view project information.

Besides, you could also create a custom group to grant or restrict permissions in project setting >> permission >> new group. Then, [change permission for the group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/change-project-level-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#change-permissions-for-a-group).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apologies but didn't provide all the details but looking to provide another user permission to add additional user permission to use a particular project with granting them project admin access